# ICS From WiFi to LAN on Win 10 pc

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, internet-connection

I'm trying to set up a small temporary 6 computer network using all Windows 10 Pro PCs running version 1803.

I am trying to share one computers WiFi connection to the other PCs over LAN using an 8 port smart switch.

I searched extensively and not found an answer, some say it's not supported anymore, some say it is but it's configuration etc.

I've tried bridging the WiFi and LAN adapters, enabling sharing on the WiFi card and enabling all the services. On this part I noticed that the services are listed with numbers 1700 - 17xx instead of the names as on win 7.

I've also gone to services.msc to check for the ICS service but it's not listed and I haven't found a way to install it.

I can config the PCs to use static IPs etc but I still haven't managed to get it to work!

Any suggestions that don't involve more hardware would be appreciated!

Comment: In principle, you need NAT and forwarding, and you need to run a DHCP server. Bridging a WLAN station and LAN doesn't work, this is a FAQ. In case it's not supported anymore on Windows 10 (no idea if it is): It's not that difficult to set up under Linux, so a VM with direct access to the WLAN card would be an alternative in a pinch.

Comment: Yes I understand that, in win 7 is was supported. It would be easier to set a static IP than run a DHCP, there are several DHCP servers for Windows too. When sharing is enabled it assigns a static IP of 192.168.137.1 subnet 255.255.255.0 but doesn't set a gateway address. I've tried using the IP of the wlan and the gateway address assigned to the wlan as the gateway for the LAN but nothing seems to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can try the following steps:

1. Right click the **wifi name**.
2. Open **Properties**.
3. Select the **Sharing** tab and check **Allow other network users to connect**. Then choose the **LAN** option from the dropdown in **Home networking connection**, and check "**Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet connection**".
4. Click "**Yes**".
5. Then there is a prompt " **When Internet Connection Sharing is enabled, your LAN adapter will be set to use the IP address 192.168.137.1 and the computer may lose connectivity to other computers on the network. If these computers have static IP addresses, you should set them to automatically obtain an IP address. Are you sure you want to enable Internet Connection Sharing?** ".
6. Click "**Yes**".
7. Now connect the laptop and smart switch with a network cable, and then connect the smart switch and 6 computers with a network cable. (tip: it should automatically obtain the IP address, no need to manually configure the IP address).
8. View if we can access Internet.

The topology map is probably like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works awesome.

Comment: Note that you can change the default IP address (192.168.137.1) by editing the Windows registry keys **ScopeAddress**, **ScopeAddressBackup** and **StandaloneDHCPAddress** in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters**. Requires reboot for the changes to take effect.